# How do you save ALL ROWS of ODBC result to array in PHP?

Tags: php, odbc

I can't seem to find a way to save all rows from odbc_exec to an array. I found php_fetch_array, but that only fetches one row at a time, requiring me to iterate through all rows to put it into an array. Is there a more concise way to do this?

Tried

```
`
$myArray = array();
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) { 
  $myArray[odbc_result($result,1)] = odbc_result($result,2); 
}`
```

and also

```
 `
$myArray = array();
while ($myRow = odbc_fetch_row($result)) { 
$myArray[$myRow['id']] = $myRow['name']; 
}`
```

but $myArray is still empty.

Comment: there is no such function, "php_fetch_array". a "fetch all" function depends entirely on your DB library, and the odbc one doesn't have it. so yes, do a `while($row = fetch...) { $data[] = $row; }` loop

Comment: As @MarcB shows the code, just create your own `odbc_fetch_all()` function or use PDO_ODBC and there is a http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @MarcB I tried doing: `while (odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $est[odbc_result($result,1)] =  odbc_result($result,2); }  ` but that didn't work :/ $est is an array()

Comment: obdc_fetch_array RETURNS the fetched array. calling odbc_result afterwards isn't going to help...

Comment: Sorry I'm a php/odbc beginner.  I also tried this. `while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) { $myArray[odbc_result($result,1)] = odbc_result($result,2); } `   but $myArray is still empty.